# Stata: Using loops for keeping and reshaping a subset of variables

Tags: stata

The raw dat. files of my dataset have  ~281.000 columns which I need to transfer to Stata and reshape. Following the suggestions on SO posted as replies to my previous posts, I am trying to use insheet command, split and reshape the chunks of data and append them. The current “toy” version of my code looks as follows:

```
insheet using "D:\Trial_Import\products_4_3_2.dat", comma clear
// extract vars

tempfile orig 1 2 3 

save `orig'

keep simulation v2-v12
save `1'

use `orig'
keep simulation v13-v22
save `2'

use `orig'
keep simulation v23-v33
save `3'

// reshape 

use `1'
reshape long v, i(simulation) j(_count)
save `1', replace

use `2'
reshape long v, i(simulation) j(_count)
save `2', replace

use `3'
reshape long v, i(simulation) j(_count)
save `3', replace


append using `1'
```

There are two issues with the code:

1)  It appends only the 1st  and 3rd data subsets, and ignores the 2nd. What could be the explanation for this? I suspect it might have something to do with using `insheet` vs. `use` when importing the raw data but I cannot figure out the way to fix it.

2)  Since the real dataset contains 281,000 variables, and I was wondering if there is a way to automatize this process (i.e. to create a loop in order to keep and reshape each 10000 vars and then the next 10000 etc…) Does anyone know if it is feasible in Stata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Issue 1.**

By the time you call -append- you have in memory dataset `3', so you're appending `1' to `3'. You've left out `2'.

Try

```
append using `1' `2'
```

**Issue 2.**

Perfectly feasible. Take a look at -foreach- and -forvalues-. Run, for example

```
help foreach
```

to see the Stata help.

**More**

I think you can shorten your code a bit doing the -reshape- after the -keep-. For example:

```
<snip>
use `orig', clear
keep simulation v13-v22
reshape long v, i(simulation) j(_count)
save `2'
<snip>
```